# How does IMAP know which emails to fetch

Tags: apache-camel, imap, email

I am using Apache Camel to monitor a email inbox. I have been trying to find out how only newly received emails since the previous poll are returned. Somehow this process will only return emails which were received between the previous poll.

Example: the poll time is set to 60 seconds. If I send one email to the inbox within this time frame one email gets handled by the route. If I send two emails in the following 60 seconds only two emails get handled by the route and not three, it ignores the first email that was handled in the previous poll. I would like to know how this happens?

I am not viewing the mailbox or marking any emails as read.

```
<camel:camelContext id="webService">
    <camel:route id="monitor">
        <camel:from uri="imap://pulp.test.uk?username=tester&amp;password=testing&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=60000" />
        <camel:process ref="storeProcessor" />
    </camel:route>  
</camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: It can keep track of what UIDs it's seen.  Or even just the highest one.  All newer messages will have higher UIDs then any message it's processed before.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the "peek" option of the camel imap component. Generally camel when fetches new emails via imap "peek" each processed message. In that case if message is processed successfully then it's marked as seen, but if there will be some error during processing then message will stay unseen. In your route you only processing unseen messages.

http://camel.apache.org/mail.html

Info about "peek" option from documentation:

> Consumer only. Will mark the javax.mail.Message as peeked before processing the mail message. This applies to IMAPMessage messages types only. By using peek the mail will not be eager marked as SEEN on the mail server, which allows us to rollback the mail message if there is an error processing in Camel.